# How to receive location updates without using a service

Tags: android

Is there an alternative to running a service to receive location updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a PendingIntent like this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 5000, intent, 0);

    manager.requestLocationUpdates(selectProvider(), 0, 0, launchIntent);
```

Your broadcast receiver should have an intent filter for the CUSTOM_INTENT in the manifest file

Comment: is there more information/context you can give with this? i need a textview to update with the current location so i was going to use a service ... or a thread ... or something, the current method i have is a workaround. what i guess im asking is how would i use this `PendingIntent` to update my textview?